# A Secret Math Society

Tags: mathematics, story, calculation-puzzle

I was about to try to join the famous Math club at my school when I stopped to hear my classmates doing the same. I didn't know that newcomers had to take a simple test to be qualified until my they tried it. It went like this:

Member :
What is 1 * 3

Newcomer A :
Is it 5?

Member :
Correct, you may go in. B, what is 1 * 4 * 5?

Newcomer B :
It's gotta be 14, right?

Member :
Indeed, you may also go in. C, what is the result of 2 * 4 * 6 * 7 * 10?

Newcomer C :
Is it 40?

Member : Wrong, but you are so close. Try again next time.

After hearing that conversation, I went to the member and said that I would like to join the club too. The member then asks, "Very well, tell me the result of 3 * 12 * 15 and if you are correct, then I will let you in."

What should I answer?

To clarify :

> The symbol (*) does not mean to multiply.

Hint (Usefulness Level : 1) :

> Observe the amount of numbers in the equations

Hint (Usefulness Level : 2) :

> The pattern only uses 3 kinds of operations.

Hint (Usefulness Level : 3) :

> Subtraction is not used in this pattern.

Additional Examples :

Member : What is 7 * 13

Newcomer D : Ummm...109?

Member : Well done! E, What is 2 * 2 * 4?

Newcomer E : I know the answer. It's 8 right?

Member : Yes, correct answer.

Extra Hints (As requested by @El-guest) :

1 * 4 = 8.5

4 * 5 = 20.5

2 * 4 = 10

2 * 2 = 4

> Please show the pattern in your answer

Comment: This riddle reminds me of [this one](https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/20169/the-club.html). The link takes you to a puzzling site called *Braingle*. You can sign in if you want :)

Comment: OK. I'll check it out @user477343

Comment: @KevinL is it possible (would it help at all) to know the answers to say 1 * 4, 4 * 5, 2 * 4, or 2 * 2?

Comment: You mean you want me to write the answers to those equations (extra hints) ? @El-Guest

Comment: Thanks @KevinL! Unfortunately I went home for the night but glad they were useful! :)

Comment: Sure no problem @El-Guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> **126**
>
> Square each value, add together, divide by numbers of values
>
> (3<sup>2</sup> + 12<sup>2</sup> + 15<sup>2</sup>) / 3 = (9 + 144 + 225) / 3 = (378) / 3 = 126

<strike>But the third clue seems to prohibit addition, so I'm not sure.</strike>
The third clue was changed to only prohibit subtraction.

Full list of equations:

> ```
> (12 + 32) / 2 = 5
>
> (12 + 42 + 52) / 3 = 14
>
> (22 + 42 + 62 + 72 + 102) / 5 = 41
>
> (72 + 132) / 2 = 109
>
> (22 + 22 + 42) / 3 = 8
>
> (12 + 42) / 2 = 8.5
>
> (42 + 52) / 2 = 20.5
>
> (22 + 42) / 2 = 10
>
> (22 + 22) / 2 = 4
> ```

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that I wrote addition was not used. Sorry I was very tired yesterday when I wrote the hints.  BTW, correct answer @hagfy

Comment: I searched for so long without using addition :(

Comment: I'm very very sorry @MarcZ

Comment: It's ok! No hard feelings

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess (tried finding random patterns). Is it

> 42

Because

> Amount of numbers * last number - first number 
>  $2 * 3 - 1 = 5$ 
>  $3 * 5 - 1 = 14$ 
>  $5 * 10 - 2 =48$ (close to $40$), so 
>  $3 * 15 - 3 = 42$

Comment: +1 Nice try but no. Going to add another hint. Btw, what I meant by close was literally really really close --> 48 is not so close to 40.

Comment: Yeah I guess that was sort of a stretch.